# iPod Shuffle (3G) - new unit is producing "usb over current notice"

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, ipod

Bought a new unit today. Seemed to be fine, synced, used it for a while.

Now whenever I plug it into a system, I either get a "usb over current notice" error, or the keyboard/mouse stops working.

MacBook (white) - all ports -> error
iMac G5 - any built-in ports -> mouse stops working 
iMac G5 - keyboard ports -> error.

Any ideas? I think the problem began when the iPod finally was fully charged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seriously sounds like their is a problem with either your USB ports on the Mac or the Shuffle itself. I would suggest taking both to your nearest iStore and have them check it out.

Comment: Went back to the store immediately (next day). They took one look at the error and did a swap.